# Click and transfer to another Collection in Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, kendo-ui

I have this. I want to click and transfer the clicked data to another collection using backbone.js Is this possible? Any ideas?

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'model/item_model',
'model/cart_model',
'collection/item_collection',
'text!templates/items/itemlist.html'
],function($, _, Backbone, Item, Cart, ItemCollection, ItemListTemplate){

var ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#mainContainer"),
events:{
    "click div.itemList" : "AddToCart"
},
initialize: function(){
  this.model = Item;
  this.collection = ItemCollection;
  this.collection.bind("reset", this.render );
},
render: function(){
  var data = {
    items: ItemCollection.models,
    item: Item
  }
  var compiledTemplate = _.template( ItemListTemplate , data);
  $("#itemContainer").html( compiledTemplate );
},
AddToCart:function(ev){
    //console.log("here");
    ev.preventDefault();
    var itemcode = $(ev.currentTarget);
    console.log(itemcode);
    //alert($(ev.currentTarget).text());
}
});
return new ItemListView;
 });
```

So since i have my click event firing up i want to click and transfer it to another collection. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [remove](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-remove) and [add](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add) functions should do the trick. A basic example

```
var c1=new Backbone.Collection([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]);
var c2=new Backbone.Collection();
var m=c1.at(1);

c1.remove(m);
c2.add(m);

console.log(c1.pluck("id"));
console.log(c2.pluck("id"));
```

Comment: What if i dont want to pluck if from c1 but instead if the user adds the same data from c1 to c2 it should update another field say like Qty. How would i update one attrib only? I always get an undefined error.

Comment: How do I force it to synchronize with the back-end server? I found out that add should be replace with create but I can't find how to force the remove to fire DELETE REST call.