# get clicked model and add to other collection in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I need to click items on ItemCollection and transfer it to CartCollection. But i can't get it to work. I need to get the model of the currentTarget clicked by the user. Any ideas? I commented out a CartCollection.add just to test it.

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'model/item_model',
'model/cart_model',
'collection/item_collection',
'collection/cart_collection',
'view/cart/cartlist_view',
'text!templates/items/itemlist.html'
],function($, _, Backbone, Item, Cart, ItemCollection, CartCollection, CartListView,          ItemListTemplate){

var ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#mainContainer"),
events:{
    "click #itemListContainer li" : "AddToCart"
},
initialize: function(){
  this.model = Item;
  this.collection = ItemCollection;
  this.collection.bind("reset", this.render );
  CartCollection.bind("add", CartListView.render());
},
render: function(){
  var data = {
    items: ItemCollection.models,
    item: Item
  }
  var compiledTemplate = _.template( ItemListTemplate , data);
  $("#itemContainer").html( compiledTemplate );
},
AddToCart:function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    // CartCollection.add([
        // {ItemCode:"item-12312",ItemDescription:"OldSomething",RetailPrice:"2",Qty:"1"},
        // {ItemCode:"item-12122",ItemDescription:"OldSometh21g",RetailPrice:"4",Qty:"2"}
    // ]);
    // var code = $(ev.currentTarget).data("ItemCode");
    // var test = CartCollection.get(code);
    // var name = test.get("ItemDescription");
    CartListView.render();
    alert($(ev.currentTarget).text());
}
});
return new ItemListView;
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click and transfer to another Collection in Backbone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882494/click-and-transfer-to-another-collection-in-backbone-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alt A: Create a view for each sub item holding the model**

When rendering chart items you can add this to a sub view where you pass model and a callback. The callback is called by each subview when it is clicked:

```
ItemView({
    model: item, 
    onAdd: this.AddToCart
});
```

In subview:

```
events: {
    "click": "onClick"    
},

onClick: function(){
    this.options.onAdd(this.model);
}
```

In parent view:

```
AddToCart: function(model){
    //Do what you what you want with the item
}
```

**Alt B: Add the model id to the `li` item and get it from a item collection**

```
<li><a href="#" data-id="<%=item.id%>">An item</a></li>
```

And then get the model from the items collection:

```
var id = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
var item = items.get(id);
```

Comment: tried your Alt B: added this to my Li <li data-id="<%= item.get("ItemCode") %>"> But when it comes to var id = $(e.currentTarget).data("id"); Firebug displays **undefined**

Comment: tried editing it by getting the cid property of the model. yet it returns undefined. following your code.

Comment: By items you mean the ItemCollection? or the one i used for data variable; items: ItemCollection.models

Comment: It worked. instead of just ID i used the cid property of the model. Thanks.